# Is it possible to achieve parallel processing in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am having a python code in AWS Lambda which is triggered based on sqs event generated.
The criteria for generating sqs is if a new file comes into a particular S3 location, then sqs will be created and which in turn calls lambda.
Right now, lambda is processing the files one after the other in a serial mode. But I would like to know if we can process multiple files at the same time.

Example: If 5 files comes to s3 location, all the 5 files should be processed parallely at the same time.

Comment: How do you know the Lambda function is being invoked serially? Yes, multiple invocations of the same Lambda function can run concurrently - make sure you configured a [function concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-aws-lambda-function-concurrency/) of more than 1. Also, is this a FIFO SQS queue?

Comment: Why are you putting SQS in the middle - S3 can notify Lambda directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might miss observed the behavior of your system. If you using the Native SQS Standar Queue with Lambda integration, the Lambdas will consume the queus in batches, you can see a detailed explanation here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-how-aws-lambda-scales-when-subscribed-to-amazon-sqs-queues/

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the SQS.

Enable triggering from the S3 `PutObject` action to the Lambda. With this, you can ensure invocations per object and also parallelism.

Answer (score -1):

Also, check your Reserve concurrency value

Doc:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

Check the concurrency dashboard in the monitoring sub section, it is already running in parallel mode.

File may look

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).